# IMAP Polling in Camel to GMAIL

Tags: xml, ssl, apache-camel, gmail, imap

So I am trying to poll my gmail through camel. I have done this a long time ago and just started up the route again for the first time.

The uri is below:

```
<from uri="imaps://imap.gmail.com?username=******@gmail.com&amp;password=******&amp;debugMode=true&amp;unseen=true&amp;consumer.delay=30000"/>
```

It is not even able to start as it cannot poll the server.

Getting error:
unable to find valid certification path to registered target

I have made sure that IMAP polling is enabled on my gmail. Not sure why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have enabled POP/IMAP forwarding
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636568332906678190-949628031&hl=en-GB&rd=1
This might help you in this case